# Maximum possible memory usage over 100%

Tags: mysql, optimization, memory

During these days I experienced several problems (delay and failed restart) on my database MySQL, so I tried with some help here around (and using Percona service too) to optimize my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file.

I'm running an Amazon t2.micro instance with 1 CPU and 1 GB of RAM with OS Ubuntu 14.04

```
# ./mysqltuner.pl

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 269M (Tables: 1078)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 403M (Tables: 218)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 428

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[--] There are 605 basic passwords in the list.

-------- CVE Security Recommendations  ---------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1h 17m 57s (23K q [5.012 qps], 2K conn, TX: 60M, RX: 1M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 85% / 15%
[--] Binary logging is enabled (GTID MODE: OFF)
[--] Total buffers: 1.1G global + 3.5M per thread (70 max threads)
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 1.1G (117.33% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 1.4G (140.96% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (2/23K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 4% (3/70)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.04%  (1/2280)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 65.5% (10K cached / 15K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (1 temp sorts / 273 sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 3% (61 on disk / 2K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (3 created / 2K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 53% (1K open / 1K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 35% (733/2K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (7K immediate / 7K locks)
[OK] Binlog cache memory access: 100.00% ( 107 Memory / 107 Total)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 20.2% (52M used / 262M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 250.0M/73.4M
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 86.1% (36K cached / 5K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 0.8% (2K cached / 2K writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 592.0M/269.2M
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[!!] InnoDB Used buffer: 21.69% (8219 used/ 37887 total)
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.99% (96339383 hits/ 96346396 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write buffer efficiency: 0.00% (0 hits/ 1 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 219 writes)

-------- ThreadPool Metrics --------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- AriaDB Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server..
```

This is my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
# GENERAL #
user            = mysql
default_storage_engine         = InnoDB
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

# MyISAM #
key_buffer_size                = 250M
myisam_recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire_logs_days               = 14

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp_table_size                 = 32M
max_heap_table_size            = 100M
query_cache_type               = 1
query_cache_size               = 16M
query_cache_limit = 10M
thread_cache_size              = 50
open_files_limit               = 1535
table_definition_cache         = 4096
table_open_cache               = 1000
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_cache_size       = 50

sort_buffer_size = 1M
join_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
max_connections = 70

# INNODB #
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size           = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 592M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 1
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_read_io_threads = 16
innodb_write_io_threads = 16

# LOGGING #
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
log_slow_queries        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
log_warnings = 0
long_query_time = 10

expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
binlog_format = MIXED

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

This is the screenshot running command `top` (**the process mysqld uses 60% of RAM**)

[image: ubuntu top command]

And buffer related settings

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';
+------------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name                | Value     |
+------------------------------+-----------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size      | 8388608   |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances | 1         |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size      | 620756992 |
| innodb_change_buffering      | all       |
| innodb_log_buffer_size       | 268435456 |
| join_buffer_size             | 1048576   |
| key_buffer_size              | 262144000 |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size      | 8388608   |
| net_buffer_length            | 16384     |
| preload_buffer_size          | 32768     |
| read_buffer_size             | 1048576   |
| read_rnd_buffer_size         | 262144    |
| sort_buffer_size             | 1048576   |
| sql_buffer_result            | OFF       |
+------------------------------+-----------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm not a MySQL expert user, what's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key_buffer, innodb_buffer_pool and innodb_log_buffer together already exhausts the available memory in a a t2 instance.

If you also consider the per thread allocations (>3M) * 70 (max connections) the possible usage is growing by another 210M minimum.

You have 270MB InnoDb data. If you don't expect it to grow significantly over time almost 600MB **buffer pool** is overkill. Make it somewhere around 300MB or if you expect it to grow then adjust with care.

The 256MB **innodb_log_buffer** is completely superfluous. It's in the same order of magnitude as your data. You're never going to write that much that needs to be buffered. Increase your innodb_log_file_size rather if you are maintaining a write heavy operation.

**Key_cache_size** is also way overprovisioned. You don't need more than what the size of your myisam indexes.

Drop your per thread buffers and improve as it is necessary.

Without seeing the usage hard to say exact numbers but I would start with something like this:

```
key_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 4M

join_buffer_size = 128k
# Increase if you have a lot of joins without indexes
sort_buffer_size = 256k
# increase if you have a lot of sorts without indexes 
read_buffer_size = 128k
read_rnd_buffer_size = 128k
```

Always test the config parameters and see what works best for your workload. Most of them are dynamic so easy too change in runtime, test, analyze and repeat until you find the best.

Comment: `# increase if you have a lot of X without indexes` - I would instead suggest to `fix your queries and indexes` if possible.

Comment: True, very true! :)

Comment: You saved me! I just try again mysqltuner here is the result http://pastebin.com/fYhvBWXC ...it's much better now but  Query cache efficiency is only 5.3% and myisam is all red. What can I do to fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: MySQL is only up for 33s. Give it a couple of hours at least to see significant results. You can see your buffer pool is not populated yet. The query cache will warm up as well. Although I wouldn't worry about that in such a small instance. All of your queries should be fetching data from the buffer pool once it's warm. MyISAM results are not really relevant for you because your data is stored in InnoDB. Anyhow after a couple of hours that should be also 'less red'.